# Order pandas dataframe on contiguous points

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe in which each row has a *row_id* as well as the boundary coordinates (left and right) of a line. The dataframe consists of lines that can be ordered such that each line connects to another one, i.e., the lines are contiguous. The way to easily see this is when the right boundary of the line at row i is equal to the left boundary of the line at row (i+1).

My goal is to find a way to achieve such an ordering based on an arbitrary initial ordering of such lines.

A simplistic example is given below. Consider the following pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'row_id':[1,2,3,4], 
    'left_coord': [(0,0), (0,1), (4,4), (1,1)], 
    'right_coord':[(0,1),(1,1),(5,7),(4,4)]
})
```

being

```
   row_id left_coord right_coord
0       1     (0, 0)      (0, 1)
1       2     (0, 1)      (1, 1)
2       3     (4, 4)      (5, 7)
3       4     (1, 1)      (4, 4)
```

For the example above, the expected result is:

```
   row_id left_coord right_coord
0       1     (0, 0)      (0, 1)
1       2     (0, 1)      (1, 1)
3       4     (1, 1)      (4, 4)
2       3     (4, 4)      (5, 7)
```

Note that in this particular case, it would suffice to order by the column `left_coord`, but in general it would not be correct.

Comment: `df2.sort_values(['left_coord'])` does this work for you? or do you require something more complex

Comment: Define "best"? In this case, you can just sort on `left_coord`, but obviously that's not a generic approach.

Comment: @wjandrea I edited the post. I would like to get a contiguous set of points when reading from left to right, top to bottom.

Comment: @SurajShourie no this doesn't work

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize each left and right match, except two, which I guess means each pair represents a line segment, right? I think graph theory is applicable here (where these would represent *edges*), but I'm not an expert. What do you need help with exactly? Are you aware of any algorithms for doing this? For example maybe you know a non-vectorized solution and just need help vectorizing it.

Comment: @wjandrea I pardon my poor explanation, I have added a general introduction to the post now. Well, I would like to see if, with some pandas dataframe manipulations, I could achieve my ordering. I know a brute-force attempt is possible but this requires looping and is therefore not efficient. A vectorized manner would be ideal

Comment: I attempted a `df.apply(lambda x: list(x['left_coord']==df['right_coord']), axis=1) and perhaps this can help to find the index where we find True in the list, which can subsequently be used with the current row position to deduce the shift?

Comment: @flow_me_over Please include your solution in the question. If it works and we just need to make it idiomatic, that's easier for us to answer than coming up with a whole algo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you want to use `networkx` and [`.eulerian_path`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.euler.eulerian_path.html#networkx.algorithms.euler.eulerian_path) ([Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path)):

```py
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "row_id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "left_coord": [(0, 0), (0, 1), (4, 4), (1, 1)],
        "right_coord": [(0, 1), (1, 1), (5, 7), (4, 4)],
    }
)

graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, "left_coord", "right_coord", edge_attr="row_id")

for edge in nx.eulerian_path(graph):
    print(edge, graph.edges[edge]["row_id"])
```

Prints:

```
((0, 0), (0, 1)) 1
((0, 1), (1, 1)) 2
((1, 1), (4, 4)) 4
((4, 4), (5, 7)) 3
```

---

To sort the dataframe:

```py
graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df.reset_index(), "left_coord", "right_coord", edge_attr="index"
)

df = df.loc[[graph.edges[edge]["index"] for edge in nx.eulerian_path(graph)]]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   row_id left_coord right_coord
0       1     (0, 0)      (0, 1)
1       2     (0, 1)      (1, 1)
3       4     (1, 1)      (4, 4)
2       3     (4, 4)      (5, 7)
```

Comment: Apart from changing `iloc` to `loc` this works great. Thanks

Comment: @flow_me_over Yes, better use `loc` (if the index is different). I've changed it in the answer as well.

Comment: It works beautifully, although I noticed that I had to add `create_using=nx.DiGraph()` in the `nx_from_pandas_edgelist`, to ensure the path is always left to right, top to bottom.

Answer (score -2):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "row_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        "left_coord": [(0, 0), (0, 1), (4, 4), (1, 1), (7, 7), (6, 6)],
        "right_coord": [(0, 1), (1, 1), (7, 7), (4, 4), (6, 6), (5, 5)],
    }
)
d = dict(df["left_coord right_coord".split()].values)
fx = lambda x: [x] if d.get(x) is None else [x, *fx(d[x])]
order = fx((0, 0))[:-1]
result = df.set_index("left_coord").reindex(order).reset_index()[[*df]]
print(result)
```